Clerk authMiddleware() is not being used even though it is in my middleware.ts file which is in the src of the application
There is an error with my clerk and middleware that I have tried to fix but nothing has worked like I tried to uninstall clerk and then reinstall it but it does nothing just shows up with this same error of
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Clerk: auth() was called but Clerk can't detect usage of 
clerkMiddleware() (or the deprecated authMiddleware()). Please 
ensure the following:
- clerkMiddleware() (or the deprecated authMiddleware()) is used 
in your Next.js Middleware.
- Your Middleware matcher is configured to match this route or 
page.
- If you are using the sre directory, make sure the Middleware 
file is inside of it.
For more details, see https://clerk.com/docs/quickstarts/nextjs
Source <unknown>
node_modules/@clerk/nextjs/src/server/createGetAuth.ts (35:15)
<unknown>
node_modules/@clerk/nextjs/src/utils/debugLogger.ts (74:19)
auth
node_modules/@clerk/nextjs/src/app-router/server/auth.ts (24:3)
src/components/leftMenu/ProfileCard.tsx (8:23) @ ProfileCard

6 | const ProfileCard = async () > {
>
7 |
8
const {userId} = auth()
9
10 |
11 |
if (!userId) return null;
Call Stack
AsyncLocalStorage.run
node:async_hooks (346:14)

